# Setting Title of Chart automatically

Tags: vba, charts

Is there anyway to have the title of a chart be equal to string variable. I recorded me manually changing the title and it came up as first activating it, then showing my text edit, but how do I do this if I don't want to activate it. I know the name of the chart is chart 1, so was trying to find a way to have the title of chart 1 be set to my string variable (which I generate from another loop elsewhere). Thx

```
activesheet.chartobjects("chart 1").activate
activesheet.charttitle.text="my text edit"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "my text edit"
```

You can read more about chartObjects [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838184.aspx)

Comment: oh perfect; this worked, thx. Is there anyway instead of saying 'ActiveSheet' to say the name of the sheet itself. Let's say, I called the Sheet, "Sheet1".

Comment: Just replace activesheet with sheets

`sheets("sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "my text edit"`

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this solution:

```
Dim var As String

Set objChrt1 = Sheets("sheet1").ChartObjects(1)
Set myChart1 = objChrt1.chart
myChart1.ChartTitle.Text = "my text edit"

var = myChart1.ChartTitle.Text
MsgBox var
```